# I am having a hard time why the if statements don't work in ShellScript

Tags: shell, for-loop, search, directory

I am having a hard wondering why is it that when i type the most random names they are accepted as a directory then. and when an if statement checks if its a readable file it says yes for all i type in. the goal here is  search for a directory check if it is a directory. then search the directory for a file then in that file search for word in it using forloops. the while loop is to ask 3 times for the file name. It a little bit rough I just need an explanation for the if statements  not working

```
 #!/bin/sh

DIR='/home/collin2/'
x=1
echo "Please enter directory"
read directory

for directory in "$DIR"; 
do
        if [ -d  "$directory" ]; 
    then echo "This is a directory Please enter the file name"
            read filename
            while [ $x -le 3 ]; do

            for filename in  "$directory";
        do
            if [ -r "$filename" ]
            then echo "The filename is readable" 
                echo "Please Enter a word "
                read word
                grep "$word" "$filename"
                exit 1


            fi

        done
        echo "Doesn't exist please try again"
        read filename 


        x=`expr $x + 1`

            done


     #exit 1

        fi

done
 echo "not a directory"
```

exit 0

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script problem, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages or you have fixed all the issues and the problem persists, then come here and ask a human.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` commands are wrong:

Wheb you write `for directory in "$DIR";`, it will set the value of the variable `directory` to `"$DIR"`. You wanted to check, that you could find `directory` in `"$DIR"` , that can be done without a `for` command:

```
cd "$DIR" || { echo "Can not go to $DIR"; exit 1; }
test -d "${directory}" || { echo "Wrong directory ${directory}"; exit 1; }
# or
test -d "$DIR/${directory}" || { echo "Can not go to $DIR"; exit 1; }
```

The same problem with the other for-loop.

The test `if [ -r "$filename" ]` should be done after `cd "$DIR/${directory}"` or include the complete path.

Comment: it doesn't make sense why the if statements dont work however your approach fixed the problem. thanks